# Unable to understand one of the parameters of asprintf() function in C

Tags: c, function

I  was actually hacking a part of code to make it useful for my purpose but I am unable to get what exactly is this statement doing :

```
    asprintf(&buffr, "%.*s", packet_length, in + 8);
```

What is meant by "%.*s" specifically ??
Is it safe to use asprintf() function ?? 
Or using snprintf() function for the same purpose would be better and reliable ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format specifier `"%.*s"` is used to print a specific number of characters from a `char*` argument (avoids requirement for null termination). In this case, `packet_length` characters will be printed from `in + 8`.

From [man asprintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf):

> The functions asprintf() and vasprintf() are analogs of sprintf(3) and vsprintf(3), **except that they allocate a string large enough to hold the output including the terminating null byte**, and return a pointer to it via the first argument. This pointer should be passed to free(3) to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.

It is safe in the sense of buffer overrun but is a non-standard function (from the linked page, it is a GNU extension). In the context of the posted code in which the size of the buffer is known prior to the `asprintf()` call, the `asprintf()` provides a convenience for the programmer in that it avoids a `malloc()` (which is necessary to avoid guessing the maximum size of the buffer to be populated).

If portability is not a requirement, then `snprintf()` offers nothing extra than `asprintf()` and `asprintf()` is more convenient to use.

<strike>As this is tagged C++ you could use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead:</strike>

```
#include <string>

std::string s(in + 8, packet_length);
```

and use `std::string::c_str()` if really required. This avoids having to manually `free()` the buffer produced by `asprintf()`.

Comment: Is it safe to use asprintf() function ?? Or using snprintf() function for the same purpose would be better and reliable ??

Comment: @Nmol, Being tagged C++, I'd go for a type safe method.

Comment: @Nmol: You've made those kinds of questions impossible to answer by tagging your question with two different languages. Unless your question specifically compares two languages, you should tag it with the language you are actually developing in and not other languages.

Comment: (I've removed the C++ tag. The existing code presumably was C, given its use of such `printf` functions)

Comment: @MSalters, removed std::string reference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, MSalters, hjmd : Apologies for my mistake. I thought as C is a subset of C++ I can include C++ tag as well. But I did get to know in detail from discussion. Thanks for giving your time in helping me out.